# How to Change Error Message CSS Style (Parsley)

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, parsley

This may seem like a spin off but the original question never got an answer and i hope i never loose points for this. So i'm using parsleyjs for my validation, awesome validation by the way but i don't like the way errors are displayed by default.

Usually, it creates a `ul` tag with a couple `li`'s and the passes the error message into them, this is fine but the problem is that I'm unable to style this `li` tags. I've tried everything. The list looks like this.

```
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5">
   <li class="parsley-required">Please choose a username</li>
</ul>
```

In my css i've tried `.parsley-error` and many other creative ways to style this element but none works. I think it may also be due to the fact that those elements are added to the dom after load time. If anyone has tackled this before, i'd appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on how and where you add you css, it would be helpful if you could provide links or code samples.

Comment: basically my styling is in a separate css file plus i move the script to the end of the stylesheet. not that it matters anyway

Comment: here is an example of how you can change the color of the error message, http://jsfiddle.net/kcv4jzch/

Comment: Thank for the help guys, u've been wonderful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to target those `li`s with any number of selectors, regardless of when they're added to the page -

`.parsley-errors-list li`

`.parsley-required`

`.parsley-errors-list .parsley-required`

to name a few. If none of those work, it's probably a specificity issue - inspecting the rendered styles in your browser's dev tools may help you out here.

Comment: Thanks , just had to fiddle with the css controls some more. got it right this time

Answer (score 2):

As i checked parsley giving this html structure for error message.

```
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5">
  <li class="parsley-required">This value is required.</li>
</ul>
```

I applied this css code to the error message.

```
.parsley-errors-list li.parsley-required {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Check the referenced url. I hope this will help you.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpmKZZ?editors=0100